# Creating this table in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

This table is not creating in oracle 10g and I dont know why, the code is

```
     CREATE TABLE  "shift" 
  ( 
   SHIFT_DATE DATE, 
   OPERATOR1 VARCHAR2(30),
   ENGINEER VARCHAR2(30),
   ENGINEER2 VARCHAR2(30),
   MANAGER VARCHAR2(30),
   SHIFT VARCHAR2(5),
 PRIMARY KEY (SHIFT_DATE) ENABLE, 
 FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER)
  REFERENCES  SHIFT_MNG (MANAGER) ENABLE
   FOREIGN KEY (SHIFT)
  REFERENCES  SHIFT_TYPE (SHIFT) ENABLE
      );
```

the Error message i get is

```
   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

skept ',' after `FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER) REFERENCES SHIFT_MNG (MANAGER) ENABLE`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma:

```
   CREATE TABLE "shift" (
           SHIFT_DATE DATE
         , OPERATOR1 VARCHAR2 ( 30 )
         , ENGINEER VARCHAR2 ( 30 )
         , ENGINEER2 VARCHAR2 ( 30 )
         , MANAGER VARCHAR2 ( 30 )
         , SHIFT VARCHAR2 ( 5 )
         , PRIMARY KEY ( SHIFT_DATE ) ENABLE
         , FOREIGN KEY ( MANAGER ) REFERENCES SHIFT_MNG ( MANAGER ) ENABLE
         , FOREIGN KEY ( SHIFT ) REFERENCES SHIFT_TYPE ( SHIFT ) ENABLE
         ^
         ^-----------this one
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

***You are missing a comma***

Oracle docs note this about ORA-00907:

ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis

Cause: A left parenthesis has been entered without a closing right parenthesis, or extra information was contained in the parentheses. All parentheses must be entered in pairs.

Action: Correct the syntax and retry the statement.

Oracle offers information regarding ORA-00907 in conjunction with FULL/LEFT OUTER joins in association with Bug 4433936.  This bug causing an ORA-00907 has been fixed in 10.2.0.3 and future versions of 11g, it can still be seen in 9.2.0.5, 9.2.0.7, 9.2.0.8, 10.1.0.5, and 10.2.0.2 in most generic platforms.

The symptoms of ORA-00907 and Bug 4433936 are simple syntax errors which happen within parsing queries associated with FULL/LEFT OUTER joins.  You can work around ORA-00907 by trying Oracle join operators to rewrite queries, as opposed to ANSI joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE  shift 
  ( 
   SHIFT_DATE DATE, 
   OPERATOR1 VARCHAR2(30),
   ENGINEER VARCHAR2(30),
   ENGINEER2 VARCHAR2(30),
   MANAGER VARCHAR2(30),
   SHIFT VARCHAR2(5),
 PRIMARY KEY (SHIFT_DATE) ENABLE, 
 FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER)
  REFERENCES  SHIFT_MNG (MANAGER) ENABLE
   FOREIGN KEY (SHIFT)
  REFERENCES  SHIFT_TYPE (SHIFT) ENABLE
      );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE  "shift" 
  ( 
   SHIFT_DATE DATE, 
   OPERATOR1 VARCHAR2(30),
   ENGINEER VARCHAR2(30),
   ENGINEER2 VARCHAR2(30),
   MANAGER VARCHAR2(30),
   SHIFT VARCHAR2(5),
   PRIMARY KEY (SHIFT_DATE) ENABLE, 
   FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER)   REFERENCES  SHIFT_MNG (MANAGER) ENABLE,
   FOREIGN KEY (SHIFT)   REFERENCES  SHIFT_TYPE (SHIFT) ENABLE
  );
```