# ORA-00907 Error when using Analytic Function in a Query (PS/Query, Peopletools 8.51.12)

Tags: oracle, plsql, peoplesoft, analytic-functions, ora-00907

Query's throwing an ORA-00907 Error when I try to paste a list of values into a criteria.

> ***Background**:* I'm not a developer, I'm just an end user that's studied enough to where I can write queries using PS/Query within Peoplesoft,
>   for my company's implementation. I work with Peoplesoft's FSCM module
>   (Financials and Supply Chain Management), currently on Version FSCM
>   8.90.08.024, using I think Oracle 11g as the base database.
>
> I'm mostly self-taught, and the technical experts we have are busy
>   with database/application stuff, or they aren't familiar with my
>   section's specific data needs.
>
> I should point out that I'm unable to directly write SQL statements to
>   Query the database. I have to use a built-in program called "PS/Query"
>   (also known as Query Manager) with a GUI that writes the SQL for you
>   and saves it as a Query that you can run to the database to extract
>   data. This is relevant to my question only in that:
>
> ```
> 1. I cannot create or alter views/tables
> 2. I cannot perform any type of SQL Statement except "SELECT"
> 3. I can embed PL/SQL, MetaSQL and plain SQL into Expressions
> 4. At this point, Query Manager is the only option I have.
> ```
>
> PS/Query is my only experience with SQL so far, aside from Oracle's
>   documentation and sites like this. From my research, it's considered
>   extremely confining by "actual" SQL programmers.The restrictions on it
>   require you to do things in a manner that violates what seem to be
>   best practices of SQL coding.
>
> **Query Request:** I have a query I've been requested to write that pulls out spend (on Vouchers and POs) against certain system-defined
>   Category Codes. What I'm trying to do is pull in Voucher IDs, sum the
>   merchandise amounts on them by Vendor and Category Code, and display
>   the results. Or in other words, for every unique combination of
>   Vendor/Category, add up all the Voucher Amounts that have that
>   Vendor/Category combination.
>
> Using the SUM (Fieldname) OVER (PARTITION BY fieldname, fieldname)
>   syntax.
>
> So the end result should look something like...
>
> ```
> Code     Vendor    Amount
> 123-45   Acme     $5000.00
> 123-45   Apple    $4200.00
> 123-46   Acme     $750.00
> ```

With that said, here's the SQL that Query Manager is displaying to get the result set I showed above:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.CATEGORY_CD, D.TN_DESCR1000, C.VENDOR_ID, E.NAME1, SUM ( A.MERCH_AMT_VCHR) OVER (PARTITION BY  D.CATEGORY_CD,  C.VENDOR_ID),E.SETID,E.VENDOR_ID 
  FROM PS_PO_LINE_MATCHED A, PS_PO_LINE B, PS_PO_HDR C, PS_ITM_CAT_TBL D, PS_VENDOR E, PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF F 
  WHERE A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
     AND A.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR 
     AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND B.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
     AND D.CATEGORY_ID = B.CATEGORY_ID 
     AND D.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(D_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL D_ED 
        WHERE D.SETID = D_ED.SETID 
          AND D.CATEGORY_TYPE = D_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
          AND D.CATEGORY_CD = D_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
          AND D.CATEGORY_ID = D_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
          AND D_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
     AND ( F.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT >= TO_DATE('2010-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
     AND F.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT <= TO_DATE('2011-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD')) 
     AND D.CATEGORY_CD LIKE :1 
     AND E.VENDOR_ID = C.VENDOR_ID 
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = F.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.VOUCHER_ID = F.VOUCHER_ID 
  ORDER BY 1
```

> **Underlying Issue:** This works fine, but it can only prompt on one
>   Category Code at a time. Category Codes are 5 digits, a 3-digit
>   "Class" followed by a dash and then a 2-digit "subclass. I have a list
>   of 375 Category Codes I need to get this Query result for.
>
> I've set up a prompt on this version that allows entry of a Wildcard
>   (So 123-%%), but that's still about a hundred separate runs of the
>   Query. Query Manager allows use of an "In List" expression type in
>   Criteria, but it requires you to manually enter each entry in the
>   list.
>
> I'm trying to set it up to where I can paste a plaintext copy of the
>   Code list into an Expression, with proper quotes/commas, and have it
>   evaluate that to give me a combined list of all the NIGP codes
>   specified. The Prompt field created by Query Manager doesn't allow
>   pasting of lists (as far as I know).

**Attempted Solution:** I viewed the page at http://peoplesoft.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/peoplesoft-other-l/create-an-expression-in-psoft-90-query-to-paste-a-list-of-emplids-2808427 and I've tried some of the answers given there, but none of them worked. That page led to me trying this modified SQL (obviously the list of codes is truncated a bit for display here):

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.CATEGORY_CD, D.TN_DESCR1000, C.VENDOR_ID, E.NAME1, SUM (  A.MERCH_AMT_VCHR) OVER (PARTITION BY  D.CATEGORY_CD,  C.VENDOR_ID),E.SETID,E.VENDOR_ID 
  FROM PS_PO_LINE_MATCHED A, PS_PO_LINE B, PS_PO_HDR C, PS_ITM_CAT_TBL D, PS_VENDOR E,  PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF F 
  WHERE A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
     AND A.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR 
     AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND B.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
     AND D.CATEGORY_ID = B.CATEGORY_ID 
     AND D.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(D_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL D_ED 
        WHERE D.SETID = D_ED.SETID 
          AND D.CATEGORY_TYPE = D_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
          AND D.CATEGORY_CD = D_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
          AND D.CATEGORY_ID = D_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
          AND D_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
     AND ( F.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT >= TO_DATE('2010-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
     AND F.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT <= TO_DATE('2011-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD')) 
     AND D.CATEGORY_CD = '005-00' OR  D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00,'' '015-06,'' '015-10,'' '615-07'') 
     AND E.VENDOR_ID = C.VENDOR_ID 
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = F.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.VOUCHER_ID = F.VOUCHER_ID 
  ORDER BY 1
```

And the SQL above is what's giving me the ORA-00907 error. Has anyone ran into this problem before? Massive wall of text, I know. My apologies. This is my first post here and I'm trying not to leave anything relevant out.

I've got the immediate problem that spurred this question fixed,but that request is just the tip of a very large iceberg, and at some point I need to figure out a way to be able to paste plaintext lists in as criteria using Query Manager, preferably in a way that plays nice with Analytic Grouping.

**TL;DR version:**

Using Peoplesoft Query Manager to do an Analytic SUM with grouping using OVER, PARTITION BY. When I try to paste a list into the criteria, it throws an ORA-00907 Error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Rhamblin, I've `oracle` to the tags as this is relevant and more people will see it. You're correct it's certainly a wall of text. I'm sorry but I can't see what's causing `ora-00907` in your last query; but, you should probably bracket that `or` or you could end up selecting a lot that you don't want. Also, is it really possible for `ps_itm_cat_tbl.effdt` to be `> sysdate`?

Comment: Thanks Ben. I think you are referring to the "OR" in the second SQL, right? I'm not sure if Query Manager's version of the SQL is a little off or what, but within the GUI it has that "OR" nested as part of the preceding "AND". Also, Query Manager is automatically building the effective date subquery. I'm not sure if I can even turn it off. I'll try putting in an explicit bracket in that OR criteria and see if that works. Thanks for putting on the new Oracle tag, and the info.

Comment: @Ben, just tried bracketing that OR segment in parenthesis. So something like 

AND D.CATEGORY_CD = '005-00' (OR  D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00,' '015-06,' '015-10,' '015-15,' '615-07') )

gets Message=ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

while

AND D.CATEGORY_CD = '005-00' OR ( D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00,' '015-06,' '015-10,' '015-15,' '615-07') )  gets the same 907 error.

Comment: I was, but it won't be causing your error. It might, however, cause logical errors. Depending on how Oracle assess your query the `or` could cause every row that matches this condition to be returned. That might be what you want but the following would be more usual: `select columns from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and ( t1.blah = 'a' or t1.oh = 'b') and t2.blah = 'f'`. Which would match both the `or` condition in the brackets and both `and`s. This is a good resource http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the link you posted](http://peoplesoft.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/peoplesoft-other-l/create-an-expression-in-psoft-90-query-to-paste-a-list-of-emplids-2808427), I see 2 methods for doing what you are trying to accomplish.
I also notice that you tried a 3rd method.

- **Method 1**

  - Criteria > Add Criteria
  - Expression Type: Character
  - Length: 255
  - Expression Text: D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00','015-06','015-10','615-07') AND 1
  - Condition Type: equal to
  - Constant: 1
- **Method 2**

  - Criteria > Add Criteria
  - Field: D.CATEGORY_CD
  - Condition Type: in list
  - Value: 015-00','015-06','015-10','615-07
- **Method 3** (Your Method)

  - Criteria > Add Criteria
  - Field: D.CATEGORY_CD
  - Condition Type: equal to
  - Define Expression: '015-00' OR D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00','015-06','015-10','615-07')

Question) Does the below exactly match the text you are putting the Expression box?

> '015-00' OR D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00','015-06','015-10','615-07')

If not, what are you putting in that box?

Comment: I ended up pulling the entire set of all codes and carving it up using Access, so I got the immediate problem completed. I'll double-check the way I formatted the query originally. Sorry for the delayed response, I've been pulled away to other stuff.

Comment: Yeah, that was the way I formatted it, on one of the tries.

I found a link here: http://peoplesoft.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/peoplesoft-hr-l/prompting-for-multiple-values-in-peoplesoft-query-3874573 that shows an alternate way to do it, but they mention that the functionality has been deprecated from current versions of Peopletools (as it let you build things that could bypass Query security, or something).

Comment: Turns out I was formatting it that way, but Peoplesoft was changing it to something else when it actually ran the SQL. I just didn't think to catch it until today. Removing the "Smart Quotes" and wrapping the entire thing in a case statement fixed it. Thank you for your help, @qyb2zm302 !

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a bit more tweaking with this, I've found what I think is the underlying issue.

The error, in this case, is two-fold. Part of it was my fault (I didn't check for Peoplesoft mangling the quotation marks I pulled from Word), and part of it was the way Query Manager interprets some kinds of functions (you have to wrap some stuff in a Case When statement to get it to evaluate properly).

### First, the "My Fault" part:

Every time I was pasting in my list of test NIGP Codes, I was doing it from a file I kept saved in Microsoft Word.

Which has the probably-handy "replace straight quotes with smart quotes" feature. Peoplesoft goes bonkers when its presented a "smart quote", and will display them as upside-down question marks (there's probably a technical term, I don't know it).

So when I'd test suggestions (such as fixing the quote/comma order as suggested by @Rene Nyffenegger and @WayneH) I'd start with my base test query, add in the expressions and test it, saving it as a separate query. If they didn't work, I'd go back to the base query. That way I could iterate changes and save potential tests as different versions.

My mistake was in not saving the different versions, leaving the application and going back in. It's when you save the query, leave the page, go somewhere else in Peoplesoft, then go back to open Query Manager that it actually shows you that it's doing the character conversion. You can't see it unless you do that. Even though Query Manager is doing it. So it was throwing a character Query Manager wouldn't recognize, but not showing me the character it wouldn't recognize.

I got a new work PC recently, and I've now disabled the Smart Quotes auto-replace for future use.

## Second, the "Query Manager: part:

On the version of this that I got to work, I made use of wrapping the "IN" function inside a Case statement. I've found that a lot of SQL functions, when used "plain" (as I'd define them by just copy-pasting from Oracle's definitions pages and filling in the appropriate variables) tend to give PS/Query (Query Manager) heartburn. But if you wrap them inside a CASE...WHEN...END statement that evaluates the result of the function and then build a criteria that selects based on certain values of that result, the function will work and properly display a result.

So for an example, set up this expression (like in the example from @qyb2zm302). I'm using different codes from what was in my original example, but they work the same (they're all five-digit, character-typed codes consisting of three digits, a dash, then two digits)

```
Case when  E.CATEGORY_CD  IN
                  ('375-15', '375-30', '375-54', '375-60', '380-30','938-63') 
    then 'true' 
    else 'false' 
    end
```

And then set a criteria:

```
    AND 
        Case when  E.CATEGORY_CD  IN
                  ('375-15', '375-30', '375-54', '375-60', '380-30','938-63') 
                   then 'true' 
                   else 'false' 
        end 
   = 'true'
```

It'll run to completion and return any rows that have that Category Code.

If you don't want to do that, you can do like in @qyb2zm302's Method 2. The only downside to that in Query Manager is that you have to enter them into individual rows in the "List", and if you can only copy-paste 25 at a time.

Wrapping it in a Case Statement lets you paste it directly into an Expression, which is far better for larger lists.

### Solutions:

The above is the code I went with that worked. It's simplifying a bit for brevity's sake, but it works.

1. **In List** works through the native Query Manager option as long as you manually-populate the list
2. **D.CATEGORY_CD = '005-00' OR** works as long as you wrap it in a Case Statement
3. **D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00','015-06','015-10','615-07')** works as long as you wrap it in a Case Statement
4. **Peoplesoft hates Smart Quotes.** None of the above will work if you're copying quotation marks directly from Word, but you won't see it unless you save, leave and come back to the same query in edit mode
5. **Formatting is important.** All of the above require the proper comma/quotation formatting, as pointed out by Rene and Wayne. Meaning: ('xxx-xx', 'xxx-01','xxx-02') etc

Thanks to everyone who helped on this! I don't think I've head-desked this hard before on any question, but I guess that's part of the learning process. Since all the answers posted are valid and correct (or at least a portion of the larger "correct"), I'm going to flag them all.

Comment: The "Case-statement-as-Criteria" method DOES NOT work with the Order By/Analytic Clause. But you can still do the manual-in-list bit.

My scope of work on using this changed between now and January, so I lost track of what my original reason for the request was. It's gone from "run this one and deliver it to consultants" to "develop a version of it to give to End-Users. So they're doing their own totaling outside the system.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
 D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00,'' '015-06,'' '015-10,'' '615-07'')
```

part looks fishy to me

Since a `''` within a string "evaluates" to a single `'` the first string is

```
'015-00,'' '
```

followed by (the non-string)

```
015-06,
```

The following `''` is probably the thing that the parser stumbles upon since it's pretty meaningless.

**Edit** try it with a `D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00', '015-06', '015-10', '615-07')`.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. My first shot at this had single quotes around each code, and that got the same error. I saw a reference at http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00907_missing_right_parenthesis.htm that suggested using "another single quote by the inner single quote". I think I may have misunderstood what he was saying, though. 

I tried changing it to read

AND D.CATEGORY_CD = '005-00' OR  D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00,' '015-06,' '015-10,' '015-15,' '615-07') 

and it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: So, if you replace it with `D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00', '015-06', '015-10', '615-07')` you still get the same error? I believe there should be *no* two consecutive (single) quotes in your expression.

Comment: Rene (@Rene): Trying it now using the formatting you suggested. It hasn't yet ran to an ORA-00907 error, but it hasn't returned a result set either. 

I think, besides removing the consecutive single quotes, that putting the commas outside the quotes may have helped too. I'll know more in (hopefully) a few. Thank you for continuing to look into this, regardless.

Comment: It keeps on timing out when I try it with the revised syntax you mentioned, Rene. I don't think it's big enough or complex-enough to be "crashing the server" (as some of our tech people put it, which makes no sense to me...). I don't have the access I'd need to be able to see error codes, message logs or times on the Query, unfortunately. And while I've got Oracle SQL Developer, I don't have the access to link it to the database to do an optimization plan.  I'm going to take a look at the code Ben suggested above.

Comment: Trying it again using our Query Scheduler. I did find something here on Stack Overflow saying something about an Oracle bug, 4433936. I don't think this is directly relevant to me (as we're on 11g), but I'm including it for reference. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009719/creating-this-table-in-oracle-10g
The scheduled query has been running for about 20 minutes now.
Edit: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699842 I'm on windows XP, so I don't know if this would directly affect me (Redhat's a linux distrib, isn't it?), but it seems semi-relevant. Afternoon full of meetings. BBL

Comment: I've played with this a bit more (changing the positioning of the commas as you recommended) and it's still throwing the same error. Your answer is factually correct, but I think there's something else still causing the problem. Does that bugzilla link mean anything to you?

Comment: Rene, (and @WayneH) Even with reformatting it to look like ('xxx-xx', 'xxx-xx', 'xxx-xx') as you suggested, it's still throwing the ORA-00907 Error. I think my problem is more with having to use Query Manager and the things it automatically builds in to try and "help" that I can't disable. Like that first "D.CATEGORY_CD =" part WayneH mentioned. I'm going to try to build a different query that's simpler to use as a test case and go from there, as this has too many confounding variables attached to it and I think I'm missing the root cause. Thank you for your help, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I think the D.CATEGORY_CD criteria are giving you the problems, I changed the double quotes to single quotes and then it still looked strange to me.  I then notice the commas are inside your quotes and not between them, try making the one criteria line look like this:

before:

```
OR  D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00,'' '015-06,'' '015-10,'' '615-07'')
```

after:

```
OR  D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00', '015-06', '015-10', '615-07')
```

Also, the "IN" is an implied "OR" and I am not sure if you have parenthesis around the two D.CATEGORY_CD,
I would just put the one additional code into the IN criteria and remove the "D.CATEGORY_CD =" line:

before:

```
AND D.CATEGORY_CD = '005-00' OR  D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00', '015-06', '015-10', '615-07')
```

after:

```
AND D.CATEGORY_CD IN ('015-00', '015-06', '015-10', '615-07', '005-00')
```

Of course, you are already ordering by CATEGORY_CD, you could remove this criteria and pull all categories in one run (that is unless there are too many rows for excel), and then you might also want to include either VENDOR_ID or NAME1 in the ORDER BY clause.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. A revised version of this with the commas outside the 5-digit codes ('xxx-xxx', 'xxx-xx', etc) is still running to an error. The first "D.Category_CD =" bit is imposed on me by Query manager, and I've yet to find a way around it. Thank you for looking at it, I'll report back soon.

Comment: I haven't tried changing the Order By yet, but I've changed the positioning of the commas in my expression as you and Rene recommended. I could probably just remove the criteria for Category Code and have it pull back everything...but there's (literally) over 9000 codes, and 200k+ Vendors. I know it'd be too big for Excel 2003, but I can export to a .txt file and import into Excel 2007. Problem is that it might be too big to run without our App Admins killing the process, and I'm "strongly discouraged" from contacting them.